# How to print two variable information to a same file

Tags: perl

I am new to perl. I am extracting some nodes information from xml file and I need to print this information in a conman file.

```
open( my $file, '>', "data" )

while ( $reader->nextElement( 'info' )) {
      my $information= $reader->readOuterXml();

      $reader->nextElement( 'address' );
      my $address = $reader->readOuterXml();

      print $file "$information\n";

}
```

How to print `$address` information to the same `$file`. please help me with this.

Comment: Are you really asking how to repeat a print statement? Why would it be any different to print `$address`?

Comment: By the comments you've made elsewhere, it seems you are asking [The Wrong Question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45154/what-is-a-better-way-to-name-the-wrong-question). You should have asked "Why does my print result in the warning 'Use of uninitialized value...'?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line after your `print` statement:

```
print $file "$address\n";
```

Comment: No I tried like this but it giving error like" use of uninitialized value $address in concatination(.) or string "

Answer (score 0):

```
print $file "$information\n";
print $file "$address\n";
```

Comment: No I tried like this but it giving error like" use of uninitialized value $address in concatination(.) or string "

Comment: Then `$reader->nextElement( 'address' );` isn't returning anything, so `$address` doesn't contain any information to print.